# Move term to another Branch - JSOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, git, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I need to do something like this.
Below image there are 3 Terms, I need to move My Term 3 , under My Term 1 ( Then My Term 3 will go as a sub-term for My Term 1.

[image]

How can i achive this using JSOM, 2013 Sharepoint.  Here i've used the code i used to reuse term, but reusing means just sharing. I though reuse the term and delete that later, but it does delete both.I just need to move, any idea? MSDN doesn't give method for moveTerm..

```js
function reuseTerm() {

    alert('check reuse');
    var sourceTermId = 'c0351a3d-5eec-454d-8bc6-4f3ac0992a84'; //Id of source Term
    var destTermId = '2085753f-2804-44c4-b16d-5b93cbbc989d';  //Id of Term below which a reused term will be created 

    var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var taxonomySession = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(ctx);
    var sourceTerm = taxonomySession.getTerm(sourceTermId);
    var destTerm = taxonomySession.getTerm(destTermId);
    
    destTerm.reuseTerm(sourceTerm, true);//I need something like destTerm.moveTerm(sourceTerm, true);
   
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(
        function () {
            alert('Reused term has been created');
        },
        function (sender, args) {
            alert(args.get_message());
        });



}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [SP.Taxonomy.Term.move Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn312574.aspx) to move the current [Term](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn312546.aspx) object to be a child of a different Term.

**Example**

```
function moveTerm(sourceTermId,targetTermId,success,error)
{
    var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var ts = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(ctx);
    var termStore = ts.getDefaultSiteCollectionTermStore();
    var sourceTerm = termStore.getTerm(sourceTermId);
    var targetTerm = termStore.getTerm(targetTermId);
    sourceTerm.move(targetTerm);
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(success,error);
}
```

**Usage**

```
SP.SOD.registerSod('SP.ClientContext', SP.Utilities.Utility.getLayoutsPageUrl('sp.js'));
SP.SOD.registerSod('SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession', SP.Utilities.Utility.getLayoutsPageUrl('sp.taxonomy.js'));
SP.SOD.loadMultiple(['SP.ClientContext', 'SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession'], function(){

   var sourceTermId = 'source-term-guid';
   var targetTermId = 'target-term-guid';

   moveTerm(sourceTermId,targetTermId,
     function(){
        console.log(String.format('Term {0} has been moved under Term {0}',sourceTermId,targetTermId));
     },
     function(sender,args){
        console.log(args.get_message());
     });
});
```

Comment: It works, Thanks a lot. Its very difficult to find resource for taxonomy sharepoint 2013. With that you had done a great contribution.